# Close source branch after pull request is merged

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I have merged a pull request on Bitbucket with the "Close source branch" option unchecked just in case further changes are made on the same branch to avoid creating an upstream.

I can still see this branch listed under "Branches" on Bitbucket.

Now that further changes are not required I would like to gracefully close the source branch opposed to deleting it but I can't see an option for this, how would I go about this?

Comment: "Close" and "Delete" are synonyms here. Closed bitbucket branches are not retained anywhere in remote repo, only your local copy may still exist (and cannot be deleted by the upstream anyway). [Asked on their forum](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/What-are-the-difference-between-branch-delete-close-or-archive/qaq-p/1946203)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the  script developed to handle deletion of all merged branches older than 30 days mentioned in "[Repository Cleanup (Merged Branch Deletion)](https://medium.com/globant/repository-cleanup-merged-branch-deletion-b41edf843117)" from [Sandeep Dubey](https://github.com/skdubey)

See [`del_branch.sh`](https://github.com/skdubey/del_commit/blob/767138e647a4520163909ba505332b5c753759da/del_branch.sh), which could be automated locally, and would fetch, then check branches from your repository, to make sure to delete them if:

- they are older than 30 days
- that are already merged